# Scrapy, New spider started in spider_closed() cannot yield requests

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

My first spider (ie. `s1`) gets a list of `id`s, ie. `[1,2,3,4,5]`. In my custom extension of `s1`, I compare the list with an existing list (ie. `self.old_products = [1,2,3,6,7]`), and find the difference, ie. `diff`. Then I pass `diff` into my second spider (ie. `s2`) to do stuff based on values in `diff`. However I couldn't make the second spider yield requests. If I comment out `yield request` in the `start_requests` method in spider2, it can `print(item_id)` correctly. Thanks.

My spider:

```
import scrapy
from missing.items import MissingItem

class S1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 's1'

    custom_settings = {
        'EXTENSIONS': {
            'missing.test_ext.ext1': 500,
        }
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        item_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
        for item_id in item_ids:
            url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{}/'.format(item_id)
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item_id'] = item_id

            yield request


    def parse(self, response):
        item = MissingItem()
        item['item_id'] = response.meta['item_id']
        yield item

class S2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 's2'

    # custom_settings = {
    #     'EXTENSIONS': {
    #         'missing.test_ext.ext2': None,
    #     }
    # }

    def __init__(self, item_ids=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(S2Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.item_ids = item_ids
        self.logger.info('Number of items to double check: %s', len(self.item_ids))

    def start_requests(self):
        self.logger.info('Double check begin')
        for item_id in self.item_ids:
            print(item_id)
            url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/0{}/'.format(item_id)
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item_id'] = item_id

            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MissingItem()
        item['item_id'] = response.meta['item_id']
        yield item
```

My custom extension:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from missing.spiders.missing_spider import S2Spider

class ext1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.old_products = [1,2,3,6,7]
        self.new_products = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ext = cls()

        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)

        return ext

    def item_scraped(self, item):
        self.new_products.append(item['item_id'])
        print('item scraped: {}'.format(item['item_id']))

    def spider_closed(self):
        print('Number of products scraped: {}'.format(len(self.new_products)))
        diff = set(self.old_products) - set(self.new_products)
        print('Diff: {}'.format(diff))

        if len(diff):
            runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

            d = runner.crawl(S2Spider, item_ids=list(diff))
            d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
            # reactor.run()

class ext2(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.new_products = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ext = cls()

        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)

        return ext

    def item_scraped(self, item):
        self.new_products.append(item['item_id'])
        print('item s2 scraped: {}'.format(item['item_id']))

    def spider_closed(self):
        print('Number of products s2 scraped: {}'.format(len(self.new_products)))
        print(self.new_products)
```

My log of spider2:

> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
>   ['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole']
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [s2] INFO: Number of items to double check: 2
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader
>   middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider
>   middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
>   []
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages
>   (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console
>   listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy
>   stats: {'downloader/request_bytes': 1347,  'downloader/request_count':
>   6,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6, 
>   'downloader/response_bytes': 12648,  'downloader/response_count': 6, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/200': 5, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,  'finish_reason':
>   'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 24, 7, 14, 16,
>   614533),  'item_scraped_count': 5,  'log_count/DEBUG': 13, 
>   'log_count/INFO': 14,  'response_received_count': 6, 
>   'scheduler/dequeued': 5,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5, 
>   'scheduler/enqueued': 5,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5, 
>   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 24, 7, 14, 15, 219602)}
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed
>   (finished)
>
> 2017-04-24 07:14:16 [s2] INFO: Double check begin

Comment: Have you looked at the [`spider_idle`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle) signal instead of `spider_closed`?

Comment: @paultrmbrth, tried engine_stopped, spider_closed, spider_idle, no differences. I guess the problem is about calling a spider in a spider, and Scrapy may not support that.

Comment: What about running your crawl sequentially in a script? See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process

Comment: @paultrmbrth, how to call that script in the first spider?

Comment: I'm suggesting using a script to call spiders via `CrawlerRunner`, not calling the script in the spider.

Comment: @paultrmbrth If using a script to call both spiders, how do I pass outputs of spider 1 to spider 2? All I want to do is to avoid writing a `txt` file to save and load the outputs.